# uib-tooltip custom trigger do not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this tooltip on a input field:

```
<input id="test" uib-tooltip="my tootip" tooltip-trigger="customEvent" ng-model="test" />
```

and i want to show it by using jquery:

```
$('#test').trigger('customEvent');
```

but i can't get it to work, my versions of ui-bootstrap-tpls is 0.14.3

i've also configured the provider like this:

```
app.config(['$uibTooltipProvider', function ($uibTooltipProvider) {
    $uibTooltipProvider.setTriggers({
        'customEvent': 'customEvent'
    });
}]);
```

Anyone could explain why?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS jquery does not support trigger() method